# How to disable keyword lighlights in a Doc block comment in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, highlight

Inside my Docbloc in WebStorm, I'm getting these highlighted keywords such as `in`, `as`, `of`, `else`.

These are obviously JavaScript keywords, but how could I disable them in Docblock?

I can't seem to find any settings for this in WebStorm configurations.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is the extension of your file (js, ts, vue, etc.)?

Comment: The extension is .ts